# Why my react app on production returns JSON instead of html

Tags: reactjs

I have created simple Todo app using create-react-app, the app only allows authenticated users to view, add, edit todos, it works perfectly in local environment however, when i deployed to Heroku and visit the todos page without logged in, the app returns json containing all todos from the database, even though the todo page supposed to be accessible only for authenticated users.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  // this condition gets ignored on production and 
  // fetches all data and displays JSON rather then rendering UI
  if (loggedInUser) {
    // fetch all todos 
  } else {
    return <Redirect to={"/users/login"}/>
  }
}, [])
```

My questions are:

1. Why does it ignore the `if (loggedIn)` condition?
2. Why does it return JSON instead of rendering the styled UI?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you are hitting the react endpoint in production and not the api itself?

Comment: @Adithya you are right! silly me I was hitting the api itself. got the point now thanks a lot.